# add light box effect to login, create account form

Tags: javascript

How to add light box effect to login, account creation, forget password and password reset forms?

Comment: Could you please show at least _some_ effort yourself? It's bad form to try to use this site to get people to do your work for you; your current low-quality "do it for me" approach will always be met with negative responses. Instead of writing a single, high-level specification for someone to fill in for you, you need to write a proper question that describes the background of your situation, and, importantly, what you've tried yourself. Please see the [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more details on what this site is about, and the quality we expect here. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Clive, I searched on google regarding this. But I didn't get result. That's why asked question directly. I will go through the help centre. Thanks for guide.

Comment: That might've sounded a bit harsh actually - not my intent at all, so sorry if that's the case. We're trying to build a repository of high quality Q+A here, so every question/answer comes under a certain amount of scrutiny. The quality/scope requirements may seem a bit pedantic at first, but it really does make for a better quality of overall site when that logic is applied over a good period of time. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 4):

Go to `admin/config/lightbox2` and then expand the Modal form settings and check the first option.

> [image]

or you can try [Ajax Login/Register](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_register) module see the [demo](http://ajax-register.drupalace.ru/).

> This module provides a smooth way for the user to login, register and
>   request new password via AJAX at any Drupal site.

or you can try [Popup](https://drupal.org/project/popup) module and don't forgot to read the [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/842032)

[image]

> The popup suite allows builders to popup tooltip-like text, nodes,
>   blocks, menus, forms, views and php-generated content.

Comment: I used lightbox2 module as you pointed out with bartik theme and it is not working for me.

Comment: @dhinesh what happen when you click on the login link ?

Comment: @dhinesh it will work on clicking the login link, not on viewing the login page, when you are in example.com/user/login

Comment: @dhinesh make an anchor tag like this "<a href="/user">Login</a>" and check if it is open as popup, if not let me know.

Comment: Did you try 'https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms' module. It will not show the user login form with lightbox library but will display in modal window.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola always use notation before name like I done, otherwise he will not be intimated

Comment: @dhinesh, Did you try 'drupal.org/project/modal_forms'; module. It will not show the user login form with lightbox library but will display in modal window.

Comment: I entered user name and password and clicked on login button. I didn't see lightbox effect. Then I clicked on Create new account and Request new password links. Default account creation and request password page opened without any effect. After that I created a content, inside that I gave <a href="?q=user">Login</a>. When I click on Login I do not see lightbox effect but it redirects to login page. I'm not yet used Modal Forms but I currently using https://drupal.org/project/ajax_register module. Give me your suggestion please.

Comment: @dhinesh Ok try like this <a href="?q=user" rel="lightbox">Login</a>

Comment: I gave <a href="?q=user" rel="lightbox">Login</a>. Lightbox effect comes but username and password fields not showing up.

Comment: @dhinesh I updated my answer, since you are struggling to setup correctly the lightbox module, alternatively you can try the  Ajax Login/Register module, It will match your case exactly.